# Bash Command (History) Number In PS1

Tags: bash, command-history, prompt

`history` lists previous commands and their number e.g.

```
$ history
286 clear
```

I want to be able to see the command number as I type a new command, instead of having to type `history`

Essentially:

`[ username ubuntu ~ ] $` becomes

`[ username ubuntu ~ ] 286 $`

Does anyone know how to achieve this in .bashrc, .bash_profile, .profile etc..?

Comment: You should answer your own question and accept that answer. That's usually how it's done on SE sites.

Comment: I see you found `\!` below; also, check out `\#`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\!` is the history number. [Source](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-ps1-10-examples-to-make-your-linux-prompt-like-angelina-jolie/).

Comment: Upvoted for answering the question without editorializing.

Comment: In `zsh` it's `%!`.

Answer (score 1):

As an heads-up, you could consider to use **[Ctrl+r]** shortcut to search backward all occurrences of the search-pattern in the history.

I found it more easy and faster to use.
Indeed typing ! and the following number that can be more than 3digits was a bit hampering at times.